# TypeError: this.navigator.element.pushPage is not a function

Tags: angular8, onsen-ui

Im using onsen-ui with angular 8 I'm getting error in the below function, I am not sure why this happens, because it is the code from the onsenUI-page.

```
push(event, value){
        console.log(value);
        this.navigator.element.pushPage(value, {animation: 'slide'});
      }
```

My code

Sidemenu.html

```
<ons-page id="menu">
<ons-toolbar>    
    <div class="center">Menu</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item (click)="push($event, 'HomeComponent')" tappable>
          Home
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item (click)="push($event, 'FormComponent')" tappable>
          Form
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
</div>
</ons-page>
```

sidemenucomponent.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild, OnsNavigator} from 'ngx-onsenui';
import { HomeComponent } from './../home/home.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'ons-page[third]',
  templateUrl: './sidemenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidemenu.component.scss'],
  providers:[OnsNavigator]
})
export class SidemenuComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private navigator: OnsNavigator) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  push(event, value){
    console.log(value);
    this.navigator.element.pushPage(value, {animation: 'slide'});
  }

}
```

Im getting error

```
ERROR TypeError: this.navigator.element.pushPage is not a function
    at SidemenuComponent.push (sidemenu.component.ts:20)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (VM5587 SidemenuComponent.ngfactory.js:21)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:42925
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
```

Below is the app component i added  but still getting same error

app.component.html

```
<ons-navigator swipeable [page]="sidePage"></ons-navigator>
<ons-page id="apppage">
<ons-splitter #splitter>
  <ons-splitter-side [page]="sidePage" side="left" width="300px" collapse swipeable>
  </ons-splitter-side>

  <ons-splitter-content [page]="contentPage">
  </ons-splitter-content>
</ons-splitter>
</ons-page>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { SidemenuComponent } from './components/sidemenu/sidemenu.component';
import { MenuService } from './menu-service.service';

import {
  Injectable,
  ViewChild,
} from 'ngx-onsenui';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';

  sidePage = SidemenuComponent;
  contentPage = HomeComponent;
  @ViewChild('splitter',{static: false}) splitter;
  constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {
    this.menuService.menu$.subscribe(() => this.splitter.nativeElement.side.open());
  }
}
```

Please can anyone help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! .. Where in your app do you have `  <ons-navigator swipeable [page]="page"></ons-navigator>`?

Comment: Yes i did leave that, i have added it now but still getting same error

Comment: Try reproducing the issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)